# How to sign a certificate with proper validation using bouncycastle

Tags: x509certificate, bouncycastle, client-certificates, pki, certificate-authority

I am trying to use BouncyCastle (1.52) on Java to create a CA certificate and then issue a client certificate from that.

I have managed to do so using the class X509v3CertificateBuilder however that class only takes the X500Name of the issuer and the private key which means no validation seems to be performed on whether the certificate being used to generate/sign the client certificate is even allowed to do so. This allow me to do things like signing a client certificate with another client certificate (BasicConstraint extension set to false) or with a certificate which does not have the correct KeyUsage extension.

Is there some class which performs all these validations upon signing in BC or is that something left to be implemented by the user?

Comment: To create a self-signed CA cert, I suggest Keystore Explorer v5, it's simple :-)

Comment: Thank you but I am not looking for a piece of software to create a self-signed CA. I can do that with BC as stated above. I am just trying to find out whether BC has a way to perform all the proper validations of creating a client or CA out of that CA